# calling a method from created hook in vuejs component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component with the following (partial) code:

```
export default {

  methods: {
    mymethod: (x) => {alert(x)},
  },

  created: () => {
    this.mymethod('success');
  },
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:578 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'mymethod' of undefined"
```

It would seem like the "this" is not being evaluated to the component's vue instance. 
And Ideas what could case this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When defining Vue methods, life-cycle methods, computed properties, ... it's better not using arrow functions, because in that way you are overriding the `this` pushed by Vue itself. Try this:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    mymethod (x) { alert(x) },
  },
  created () {
    this.mymethod('success');
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have used the arrow function in *created* hook. Try using

```
created: function {
   this.mymethod('success');
},
```

if you check the [vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) documentation that also clearly states

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as
> created: () => console.log(this.a) or vm.$watch('a', newValue =>
> this.myMethod()). Since arrow functions are bound to the parent
> context, this will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect, often
> resulting in errors such as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> of undefined or Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

First change your hook method to this :

```
methods: {
  mymethod(x){alert(x);}
}
```

Then, also change the called methods inside the created hook function. It must look like this :

```
created(){
  this.mymethod('success');
}
```

Then you are done!

Answer (score 0):

We generally should avoid arrow function in object.

```
export default {
  methods: {
    mymethod (x) { // something },
  },
  created () {
    this.mymethod('success');
  },
}
```